# How to set a transparent background color and do antialising for kivy images?

Tags: python, image, transparency, kivy, antialiasing

I whant to use an image with transparent background. The common kivy "Image" class offers the loading of a file into an image. But I found no way to set a transparent background color and set antialising.

Comment: Does the image actually have a transparent background? Can you post an example demonstrating the problem, including the image, if so?

Answer (score 1):

Only a partial solution.
The image class has not flags or colors to set for transparency. BUT it is possible to perform an alpha blending, by overlaying two images. For that the "opacity: " property has to be set. The mixing of two images is undertaken by following code:

```
<MixImage@FloatLayout>:
    Image:
        id: img1
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.size
        source: 'gfx/im1.png'
        opacity: 1.0
    Image:
        id: img2
        pos: root.pos
        size: root.size
        source: 'gfx/im2.png'
        opacity: 0.5
```

I found no parameter to do antialising.